# Fill layers blender python

Tags: python

I'm actually using blender / python to use blender as a slicer.
With a 3D piece (like Suzanne) i'm able to slice it
After doing that, i get something like this (example for slicing Suzanne)

[image]

Now i want to know if it's possible to fill the different layers ?
I can do it manually, by selected the vertices and press F (in edit mode) but i dont get a clean result as you can see below:

[image]

Does someone have an idea to do the filling properly ? (if possible by using blender python) !

Here the actual code:

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)
#bm.from_object(ob, scene)
bm.transform(ob.matrix_world)

#bmesh.ops.triangulate(bm, faces=bm.faces)

cut_verts = []
cut_edges = []

for i in range(0, 45, 1):
    ret = bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(bm, geom=bm.verts[:]+bm.edges[:]+bm.faces[:],
              plane_co=(0,0,i/20), plane_no=(0,0,-1))
    
    cut_verts.extend([v.index for v in ret['geom_cut'] if isinstance(v, bmesh.types.BMVert)])
    cut_edges.extend([e.index for e in ret['geom_cut'] if isinstance(e, bmesh.types.BMEdge)])
    
    



bm2 = bm.copy()


for e in bm2.edges:
    if e.index not in cut_edges:
        bm2.edges.remove(e)

for v in bm2.verts:
    if v.index not in cut_verts:
        bm2.verts.remove(v)


bm2.to_mesh(me)
ob.matrix_world = Matrix()
me.update()
```

Thank you a lot for your help !

Comment: a partial solution is to use `bmesh.ops.edgeloop_fill` on the edges generated by the bisect, but that stops working part way through the monkey.  I tried this by inserting two statements `edges = [e for e in ret['geom_cut'] if isinstance(e, bmesh.types.BMEdge)]` and  `bmesh.ops.edgeloop_fill(bm, edges=edges)` immediately after the bisect.  Perhaps you can figure out why it fails and work around it.

Comment: if you close holes to make a manifold mesh then it should work better... you may do it from the script or try 3d print toolbox included addon